# How to compare the last digits of consecutive integers in a list?

Tags: python, list

In a program that I am creating I need to add integers from a file into a list, and then determine the last digit of each integer and compare it to the following integer's last digit, and continue in this cycle until each integer in the list has been compared with the following one and the results stored. I am able to add the integers from a file into the list and determine the last digit of each integer, but I am unable to compare the last digits. I've been using the code,

```
with open('test.txt') as f:
    my_list = []
    for line in f:
           my_list.extend(int(i) for i in line.split())

for elem in my_list:
    nextelem = my_list[my_list.index(elem)-len(my_list)+1]

one_followed_by_1 = 0
one_followed_by_2 = 0
one_followed_by_3 = 0
one_followed_by_4 = 0

for elem in my_list:
    if elem > 9:
        last_digit = elem % 10
        last_digit_next = nextelem % 10
        if last_digit == 1 and last_digit_next == 1:
            one_followed_by_1 += 1
        elif last_digit == 1 and last_digit_next == 2:
            one_followed_by_2 += 1
        elif last_digit == 1 and last_digit_next == 3:
            one_followed_by_3 += 1
        elif last_digit == 1 and last_digit_next == 4:
            one_followed_by_4 += 1

print one_followed_by_1
print one_followed_by_2
print one_followed_by_3
print one_followed_by_4
```

But that is not working for me. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You make things too complicated. First of all, we can simply write the parser like:

```
with open('test.txt') as f:
    my_list = [int(i) for line in f for i in line.split()]
```

Next instead of constructing a `nextelem` that complicated way, we can use `zip(my_list,my_list[1:])`, to iterate over the current and next item concurrently:

```
for n0,n1 in zip(my_list,my_list[1:]):
    pass
```

Now of course we still need to **process the counts**. We can however do this with the `Counter` of the `collections` library. Like:

```
from collections import Counter

ctr = Counter((n0%10,n1%10) for n0,n1 in zip(my_list,my_list[1:]))
```

So we do not even need the `for` loop. Now a `Counter` is a dictionary. It maps **tuples `(i,j)`** on the count `cij` of the number of numbers that end with `i` that are followed by a number that ends with `j`.

For instance, print the numbers, like:

```
print ctr[(1,1)] # 1 followed by 1
print ctr[(1,2)] # 1 followed by 2
print ctr[(1,3)] # 1 followed by 3
print ctr[(1,4)] # 1 followed by 4
```

Or the program in full:

```
from collections import Counter

with open('test.txt') as f:
    my_list = [int(i) for line in f for i in line.split()]

ctr = Counter((n0%10,n1%10) for n0,n1 in zip(my_list,my_list[1:]))

print ctr[(1,1)] # 1 followed by 1
print ctr[(1,2)] # 1 followed by 2
print ctr[(1,3)] # 1 followed by 3
print ctr[(1,4)] # 1 followed by 4
```

Comment: Thank you so much it is much simpler and it works. Your `with open('test.txt') as f:
    my_list = [int(i) for i in line.split() for line in f]` didn't work for me  (name 'line' is not defined) but when I used the version of that line that I originally had it worked

Comment: @Sekou: sorry, I swapped the `for`s. The edit should work.